# Scanning through a jTextArea for a word

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am trying to create a search bar that highlights the corresponding word in a text area. The problem that I have is the code sample below only highlights the first occurrence of the word in the text area i.e. it does not scan through the whole text area. How do I make it so that all occurrences of the keyword will be highlighted?

```
public void keywordSearch() {
    hilit.removeAllHighlights();
    String keyword = txtSearch.getText();
    String content = txtArea.getText();
    int index = content.indexOf(keyword, 0);
    if (index >= 0) {  // if the keyword was found
        try {

            int end = index + keyword.length();
            hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
            txtSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        txtSearch.setBackground(ERROR_COLOR);// changes the color of the text field if the keyword does not exist
    }
}
```

I have tried the following fix using the Scanner class but it still does not work.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(content);

    if (index >= 0) {  // if the keyword was found
        try {
            while(sc.hasNext() == true)
            {
                int end = index + keyword.length();
                hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
                txtSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                sc.next();
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Fix using while loop (entered an infinite loop)

```
    while(index >= 0) {   // if the keyword is found
        try {
            int end = index + keyword.length();
            hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
            txtSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            index = content.indexOf(keyword, index);
            System.out.println("loop");// test to see if entered infinite loop

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is here:

```
int index = content.indexOf(keyword, 0);
if (index >= 0) {  // if the keyword was found
```

Change this to a while loop searching again from the index you found the first time:

```
int index = content.indexOf(keyword, 0);
while (index >= 0) {  // if the keyword was found
    // Do stuff
    index = content.indexOf(keyword, index);
}
```

You will also need to change your final else to do another check to see whether it existed at all (there are several ways you can do that).

Comment: Tried this but it entered an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3469429 You probably need to scan from index+1 on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You are only looking for one occurrence of the word.

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++){

  int index = content.indexOf(keyword, i);
  if (index >= 0) {  // if the keyword was found

    int end = index + keyword.
    hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
    txtSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

  }
...
```

This for-loop will search through the entire conent-string and send all the occurrences of the keyword to the addHighlight-method.

Comment: Ugh. Don't do this. It will "work" in that it does highlight every word but it's horribly inefficient as you will repeatedly find and highlight the same word over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
ArrayList<Integer> keywordIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int index = content.indexOf(keyword, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++){
    if (index >= 0) { // if keyword found

    int end = index + keyword.length();
    keywordIndexes.add(index); // Add index to arraylist
    keywordIndexes.add(end);  // Add end to next slot in arraylist
}

for(int j = 0; j < keywordIndexes.size(); j+=2){
    hilit.addHighlight(j, (j+1), painter);
    txtSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
...
```

This might not be the most optimized code but it should work.